# Finding equivalent program to proof in typed lambda calculus

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have the following proof that assuming A and B, one can derive A ∧ B:

[image]

I am trying to find an equivalent program to this proof, in typed lambda calculus using Haskell-style syntax for pairs. It is assumed that a : A and b : B.

Translating this proof to types, one gets: assuming x :: (B,A) one wants to construct (A,B).

I am stuck between two options for this:

(1) (λx. ( x, x)) (b,a)

(2) ( (b,a), (b,a))

I believe that it is option (2) that is correct, since it is not an implication (which translates to a function) that is being proved. However I am not sure if my reasoning is correct. Since we are considering this proof in terms of types, where x :: (B,A) is option (1) more appropriate? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Both (1) and (2) have the same types, so any reasoning which goes *only* by types and does not consider the actual proof-term given cannot possibly distinguish between the two. So... no, your reasoning is not correct.

Comment: What is the difference between these two options, if any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the correct line of reasoning. We will start with a "hole", and slowly expand the hole following the next proof rule. I'll follow your lead and assume there are two terms in scope, named `a` (of type `A`) and `b` (of type `B`). We start with just a hole:

```
_
```

The last proof rule used is →-E (arrow elimination); in the lambda calculus, this corresponds to function application.

```
_ _
```

Since the proof term for the second hole is smaller, let's start with that one. That rule is ∧-I (conjunction introduction); the corresponding lambda term is `(,)`.

```
_ (_, _)
```

The assumptions used by the conjunction introduction are `B` and `A`; our corresponding lambda terms are `b` and `a`. So:

```
_ (b, a)
```

This concludes this branch of the proof term. Now we must ascend the left branch. The rule used to supply the function is →-I<sup>δ</sup> (arrow introduction using variable δ); in lambda calculus, the corresponding term is a lambda.

```
(\δ -> _) (b, a)
```

Next up is a conjunction introduction. As before, the corresponding term is `(,)`.

```
(\δ -> (_, _)) (b, a)
```

Here the proof branches. For consistency with our previous go, we'll follow the right branch first, then the left branch. The next rule up in the right branch is ∧-E<sub>1</sub> (conjunction elimination 1); the corresponding term in lambda calculus is `fst`.

```
(\δ -> (_, fst _)) (b, a)
```

The last rule in this branch is δ (variable elimination of variable δ);  the corresponding lambda calculus term is `δ`.

```
(\δ -> (_, fst δ)) (b, a)
```

Now following the left branch of the proof, the next rule used is ∧-E<sub>2</sub> (conjunction elimination 2) -- `snd` in the lambda calculus.

```
(\δ -> (snd _, fst δ)) (b, a)
```

The final rule used is again variable elimination (again with variable `δ`).

```
(\δ -> (snd δ, fst δ)) (b, a)
```

We have now reached the top of every branch of the proof term (and filled all the holes), so we are done building our lambda calculus term. Looks like it corresponds with your (1)! Can you see how the proof term would have to change to correspond with your (2)?

Comment: "it seems that this particular proof syntax doesn't indicate which variable should be used" -- I think "delta" is the name of the variable, and not the name of the rule. ->I^delta corresponds to `\delta -> _`, and the `delta` rule for that variable `delta`.

Comment: @chi Ah, that could be! I have optimistically updated the answer under that assumption, as it seems like a particularly clean and likely one to make.

Comment: I think `((\ b a -> (b,a)) b a)` ought to be written explicitly, to correspond to the right sub-proof, constructing the `(b,a)` from the given `a` and `b`, as expected by the left sub-proof.

Comment: @WillNess There is no →-E in the right sub-proof, hence no function application. (In this context, `(,)` is not a function, but a piece of syntax.) So it certainly shouldn't be `f b a` for any function `f`, including `f = \b a -> (b,a)`. I don't know what the "as expected by the left sub-proof" subcomment means at all.

Comment: OK, so maybe the `(b,a)` could be written as `((,) b a)` there to stress the fact that we start from A and B, not from B/\A. "as expected by" I don't understand what's unclear. `(\(b,a) -> ...)` needs a `(b,a)` term to be applied to. the function expects that term as its argument in the application. if we'd be given only A as a premise, we'd not be able to construct the `(b,a)` term there, that's all.

Comment: @WillNess Okay. I don't see that `(,) b a` is any more clear than `(b,a)` -- just different spellings of the same thing. So I will keep the more common choice of `(b,a)`.

Comment: @WillNess As for "`(\(b,a) -> ...)` needs a `(b,a)` term to be applied to", I don't admit this fact, and also `(\(b,a) -> ...)` does not appear in the answer. So I still don't understand your "as expected by the left sub-proof".

Comment: Well, I think I explained what I meant. I do think `(b,a)` ought to appear as the parameter there instead of `delta`. that doesn't mean it is right, I could very well have been mistaken there, but I think it explains my meaning. I really can't see what more can I add here.

Comment: yep, `(\(b,a) -> ...)` looks to have been wrong, as typed lambda calculus seems to not have pattern matching...